# Pandas order rows by datetime month given external order

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

So I'm having a little trouble ordering my Dataframe, I've tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27255567/1695437) question, but haven't managed to get it to work. What I have is a Dataframe `nudf` like so:

```
                     date  level_1      0 
0     2016-10-01 00:00:00      0.0  74.00    
1     2016-10-01 00:30:00      0.5     72    
2     2016-10-01 01:00:00      1.0     70    
3     2016-10-01 01:30:00      1.5     64    
4     2016-10-01 02:00:00      2.0     63    
5     2016-10-01 02:30:00      2.5     60    
...                   ...      ...    ...   
19003 2017-09-31 21:30:00     21.5    129    
19004 2017-09-31 22:00:00     22.0    118    
19005 2017-09-31 22:30:00     22.5    106  
19006 2017-09-31 23:00:00     23.0     84    
19007 2017-09-31 23:30:00     23.5     76
```

And what I would like to do is order the rows by an external month order:

`[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]`

This is the last 12 months, from last month. I'd like to ignore the year and order each month block of rows in accordance with the order above.

For example, given the following rows:

```
0     2016-02-01 00:00:00      0.0  74.00    
1     2016-02-01 00:30:00      0.5     72    
2     2016-03-01 01:00:00      1.0     70    
3     2016-03-01 01:30:00      1.5     64    
4     2017-04-01 02:00:00      2.0     63    
5     2017-04-01 02:30:00      2.5     60
```

The result should be:

```
4     2017-04-01 02:00:00      2.0     63    
5     2017-04-01 02:30:00      2.5     60
0     2016-02-01 00:00:00      0.0  74.00    
1     2016-02-01 00:30:00      0.5     72    
2     2016-03-01 01:00:00      1.0     70    
3     2016-03-01 01:30:00      1.5     64
```

I've tried:

```
nudf['month'] = nudf.apply(lambda row: row.date.month, axis=1)
nudf.month = nudf.month.astype("category")
nudf.month.cat.set_categories([x.month for x in reversed(_get_last_x_months(12))], inplace=True)

nudf.sort_values(["month"], inplace=True)
```

But the day and hour order is not maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a separate [**`categorical`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html), `argsort`, and `iloc`
Also, notice I used `kind='mergesort'` because `mergesort` is a "stable" sorting algorithm and will maintain relative order for equivalently valued rows.

```
mcats = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
nudf.iloc[pd.Categorical(nudf.date.dt.month, mcats, True).argsort(kind='mergesort')]

                 date  level_1     0
4 2017-04-01 02:00:00      2.0  63.0
5 2017-04-01 02:30:00      2.5  60.0
0 2016-02-01 00:00:00      0.0  74.0
1 2016-02-01 00:30:00      0.5  72.0
2 2016-03-01 01:00:00      1.0  70.0
3 2016-03-01 01:30:00      1.5  64.0
```

---

You can add the column as well

```
mcats = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
nudf = nudf.assign(month=pd.Categorical(nudf.date.dt.month, mcats, True))
nudf.sort_values('month', kind='mergesort')

                 date  level_1     0 month
4 2017-04-01 02:00:00      2.0  63.0     4
5 2017-04-01 02:30:00      2.5  60.0     4
0 2016-02-01 00:00:00      0.0  74.0     2
1 2016-02-01 00:30:00      0.5  72.0     2
2 2016-03-01 01:00:00      1.0  70.0     3
3 2016-03-01 01:30:00      1.5  64.0     3
```

---

If we are trying to sort by month then by date, we don't need to specify a stable sort and just sort by two columns

```
mcats = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
nudf = nudf.assign(month=pd.Categorical(nudf.date.dt.month, mcats, True))
nudf.sort_values(['month', 'date'])
```

Or instead of the `argsort` answer, we can use `np.lexsort` to return an ordering permutation based off of multiple arrays.

```
mcats = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
nudf.iloc[np.lexsort(
    [nudf.date, pd.Categorical(nudf.date.dt.month, mcats, True)]
)]
```

Comment: Another one of those handy pandas things I never knew about. very interesting answer! I was wondering how the order worked... i'll give it a test

Comment: As you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/lutrasdebtra/4d811cd8baffd1cef9243e6dd907dd3b), the order is not correct for the larger file I have.

Comment: I altered my post to specify a stable sorting algorithm.  See if that helps.

Comment: Works perfectly with the mergesort addition. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the ordering by using `%`. But to get your desired output, first sort by datetime.

```
nudf.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)

mcats = [x.month for x in reversed(_get_last_x_months(12))]
#[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3]
nudf['m_fake'] = (nudf.date.dt.month+(12-mcats[0]))%12
nudf.sort_values(by='m_fake')

#                 date  val1  val2  m_fake
#4 2017-04-01 02:00:00   2.0    63       0
#5 2017-04-01 02:30:00   2.5    60       0
#0 2016-02-01 00:00:00   0.0    74       10
#1 2016-02-01 00:30:00   0.5    72       10
#2 2016-03-01 01:00:00   1.0    70       11
#3 2016-03-01 01:30:00   1.5    64       11
```

Comment: The ordering is generated by `[x.month for x in reversed(_get_last_x_months(12))]`, so I'd ideally like to use that.

Comment: okay, then you'd just need to do 12-order[0] to never have to worry about it again

Comment: As can see [here](https://gist.github.com/lutrasdebtra/46a0c1ac47ed12cdff10630da456c4de), on the larger dataset, some days are out of order.

Comment: That's because in the large file they aren't sorted by date, while in the example they were. I just updated to sort first based on date and then apply the month ordering. That should do it.

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake, your answer does also appear to work - thanks for your help, the other answer came in first, but this is also a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to change the value and re-order the columns

```
# creates an int value based on the date using .dt.month (must be a date type)
df['month_value'] = df['date'].dt.month

# creates a dictionary that will remap the values
new_order = {4:1, 5:2, 6:3, 7:4, 8:5, 9:6, 10:7, 11:8, 12:9, 1:10, 2:11, 3:12}

# creates a new column based on the mapping
df['new_value'] = df['month_value'].map(new_order)

# sorts the values based on the new column
df.sort_values(by='new_value')

           date  month_value  new_value
4 2017-04-01            4          1
5 2017-04-01            4          1
0 2016-02-01            2         11
1 2016-02-01            2         11
2 2016-03-01            3         12
3 2016-03-01            3         12
```