# How to Sort a Pandas Column by specific values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting

Let's say, for the sake of this question, I have a column titled `Blah` filled with the following data points (I will give it in a list for clarity):

`Values = ['one', 'two', 'four', 'six', 'nine']`

How could I choose to sort by specific values in this column? For example, I would like to sort this column, `Blah`, filled with the values above into the following: `['nine', 'four', 'two', 'six', 'one']`.

Unfortunately, it is not as easy as just sort_values and choose alphabetical!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482668/sorting-by-a-custom-list-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

What are you sorting by? Alphabetical would be ['four', 'nine', 'one', 'six', 'two']

Comment: As stated, it is not a sort by alphabetical order. Ashemag already referred me to my question being answered; thank you anyways for the feedback!