# Add Multiple sort on Dataframe one via list and other by date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
Name    values   Status          CompletedOn
ac       100    Pending      2019-01-10T03:59:42.184+00:00
as       10     Pending      2019-06-10T03:59:42.184+00:00
sd       10     Closed       2019-12-10T03:59:42.184+00:00
es       10     Closed       2019-12-11T03:59:42.184+00:00
sg       5      Closed       2020-12-10T03:59:42.184+00:00
er       10     optional     2019-12-14T03:59:42.184+00:00
rw       10     optional     2019-12-15T03:59:42.184+00:00
```

I want to sort them on the basis if `list vals=['pending','optional','Closed']` and Completed on Date corresponding to the status.

I have tried [sorting by a custom list in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482668/sorting-by-a-custom-list-in-pandas)
but unable to figure out the method to sort them on basis of date also.

So the output Dataframe would be like

```
Name    values   Status          CompletedOn
ac       100    Pending      2019-06-10T03:59:42.184+00:00
as       10     Pending      2019-01-10T03:59:42.184+00:00
er       10     optional     2019-12-15T03:59:42.184+00:00
rw       10     optional     2019-12-14T03:59:42.184+00:00
sg       5      Closed       2020-12-10T03:59:42.184+00:00
es       10     Closed       2019-12-11T03:59:42.184+00:00
sd       10     Closed       2019-12-10T03:59:42.184+00:00
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go, and see if it fits ur use case:

The idea is to get the Status column as a [category](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) data type, with the category orders included in the conversion. You can then sort on both Status and CompletedOn, and include the ascending parameters

```
#convert Status to category dtype
df.Status = pd.Categorical(df.Status, categories = ['Pending','optional','Closed'])

#sort columns with ascending options for the columns
df.sort_values(['Status', 'CompletedOn'],ascending = [True,False])

      Name  values   Status            CompletedOn
1     as    10      Pending     2019-06-10 03:59:42.184000+00:00
0     ac    100     Pending     2019-01-10 03:59:42.184000+00:00
6     rw    10     optional     2019-12-15 03:59:42.184000+00:00
5     er    10     optional     2019-12-14 03:59:42.184000+00:00
4     sg    5      Closed       2020-12-10 03:59:42.184000+00:00
3     es    10     Closed       2019-12-11 03:59:42.184000+00:00
2     sd    10     Closed       2019-12-10 03:59:42.184000+00:00
```