# sortindex() for a string index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Method Dataset          
A1     B2        10   20
       B3        10   20
       B1        10   20
       B1        10   20
A2     B2        10   20
       B1        10   20
A3     B9        10   20
       B5        10   20
```

The `Dataset` index is a string. How can I sort just the second (`Dataset`) index using a list like `["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"]` ? I think I'm looking for `sortindex()` but with custom ordering.

Comment: Try `df.sort_index(level=1)`

Comment: I think `sort_index` works on string index by alphanumerical order, and your list seems to follow this order, is it what you want? or I`m missing something

Comment: Oh that was just an example. I do want a very specific sorting that's not alphanumerical.

Comment: The MultiIndex might complicate things a bit, but there are several options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482668/sorting-by-a-custom-list-in-pandas, a categorical dtype might be the simplest.