# Sort 2 columns in pandas keeping 1 additional column fixed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
X    Y        Z
AB  bat     0.51184607
AB  ball    0.45687276
AB  cat     0.5428388
CD  apple   0.89665717
CD  tiger   0.6785901
CD  bench   0.787102
CD  dragon  0.8066087
```

I want to sort the dataframe based on column Z values in descending and accordingly get the respective Y column values but keeping column X as constant. So the output should look like:

```
X    Y         Z
AB  cat     0.5428388
AB  bat     0.51184607
AB  ball    0.45687276
CD  apple   0.89665717
CD  dragon  0.8066087
CD  bench   0.787102
CD  tiger   0.6785901
```

How can I effectively do this in pandas

Comment: `df.sort_values(['X','Z'], ascending=[True,False])`?

Comment: For cases where `X` must remain fixed but does not have an alphanumeric order, it would have to first be converted to dtype `category` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13839029/14148248).

Answer (score 2):

You can do `sort_values`

```
df = df.sort_values(['X','Z'],ascending=[True,False])
Out[74]: 
    X       Y         Z
2  AB     cat  0.542839
0  AB     bat  0.511846
1  AB    ball  0.456873
3  CD   apple  0.896657
6  CD  dragon  0.806609
5  CD   bench  0.787102
4  CD   tiger  0.678590
```

Answer (score 0):

this work, but inefficient：

```
def sort_cols(df, cols):
    df = df.sort_values(cols)
    return df

new_df = df.groupby('X').apply(sort_cols, cols='Z').reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.merge(df, new_df, one=df.columns.tolist())
```

another way from [sorting by a custom list in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482668/sorting-by-a-custom-list-in-pandas)

```
sorter = df.X.unique()
df.X = df.X.astype('category')
df.X = df.X.cat.set_categories(sorter)
df = df.sort_values(['X', 'Z'])
```