# Remove columns that have substring similar to other columns Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `dataframe` where the column names have the same format: `data_sensor`, where the date is in the format of `yymmdd`. Here is a subset of it:
[image]

Considering the last data (`180722`), I would like to keep the column according to sensor pre-defined priority. For example, I would like to define that `SN1` is more important than `SK3`. So the desired result would be the same `dataframe`, only without column `180722_SK3`. The number of columns with the same last date can be more than two.

This is the solution I implemented:

```
sensorsImportance = ['SN1', 'SK3'] #list of importence, first item is the most important
sensorsOrdering = {word: i for i, word in enumerate(sensorsImportance)}


def remove_duplicate_last_date(df,sensorsOrdering):
    s = []
    lastDate = df.columns.tolist()[-1].split('_')[0]
    for i in df.columns.tolist():
        if lastDate in i:
            s.append(i.split('_')[1])

    if len(s)>1: 
        keepCol = lastDate +'_'+sorted(s, key=sensorsOrdering.get)[0]
        dropCols = [lastDate +'_'+i for i in sorted(s, key=sensorsOrdering.get)[1:]]
        df.drop(dropCols,axis=1,inplace=True)
        
    return df
```

It works fine, however, I feel that this is too cumbersome, is there a better way?

Comment: Can you show the data frame no like pic ?

Comment: Here's [how to make good reproducible examples in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/6692898)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sorting by a custom list in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482668/sorting-by-a-custom-list-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, with `split` the column then apply the `argsort` with the list , then reorder your dataframe , and join back the columns after `groupby` get the first value by date

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('_').map(tuple)
sensorsImportance = ['SN1', 'SK3']
idx=df.columns.get_level_values(1).map(dict(zip(sensorsImportance,range(len(sensorsImportance))))).argsort()
df=df.iloc[:,idx].T.groupby(level=0).head(1).T
df.columns=df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Comment: Hi @YOBEN_S, thank you. However, one major and one minor thing are not adequate to my problem. The minor thing is that the returned `df` is not ordered by columns name as the original `df` is, but this can be easily solved with `df.loc[:,sorted(df.columns.tolist())]`. The major thing is that I might have duplicate dates in the `df` which I would like to keep (remove only the last column/s in case there are duplicate dates in it), hence the `groupby` removes also duplicate dates that are not in the last column, duplicate dates which I would like to keep.