# How to change the order of elements in a column in PANDAS (elements are not numbers)

Tags: pandas

I need help with changing the order of elements in a column of my table.
The elements are strings and I have a specific order that I would like them to be sorted.

For example if I would have a table of which one column would be days of the week I would want them to be ordered in a right way.

| A header | weekdays |
| --- | --- |
| smth | friday |
| smth | monday |

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482668/sorting-by-a-custom-list-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Categorical` with `ordered=True`:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['b','c', 'd'], 'day':['Mon', 'Fri', 'Tues']})

# all the week days in order you choose
weekdays = ['Mon','Tues', 'Fri']

# convert to categorical
df['day'] = pd.Categorical(df['day'], categories=weekdays, ordered=True)

# sort as usual
df.sort_values('day')
```

output:

```
   a   day
0  b   Mon
2  d  Tues
1  c   Fri
```