# arrange rows by list python

Tags: python, list

I can't manage to write a good script. Script order table (first column) by order. It should arrange each line, and give only the first occurrence.... I don't know how I could fix it.

EXAMPLE TABLE

```
A       B
1211    ds
3245    ssssd
3114    dsf
3114    apple
4324    sssvdff
4324    weewr
4324    bla 
4324    orange
1211    something
1211    blue
```

ORDER LIST EXAMPLE

```
4324\n
3245\n
3114\n
1211\n
```

ORDERED TABLE (what I get)

```
A       B
4324    sssvdff
3245    ssssd
3114    dsf
1211    something
```

ORDERED TABLE (what I want)

```
A       B
4324    sssvdff
4324    weewr
4324    bla 
4324    orange
3245    ssssd
3114    dsf
3114    apple
1211    something
1211    blue
```

CODE:

```
import re

def map_ids_to_row_list(_id):
    _id = _id.strip('\n')
    for s in lines:
        if re.search(_id,s):
            return s

file = open('Lorder.txt', 'r').readlines()
names = []
for name in file:
    names.append(name.strip('\n'))

name = 'table_data.txt'
name_split = name.rsplit('.',1)
new_name = name_split[0] + '_sorted.csv'
    
table = open(name,'r')
table_read = table.readlines()
    
lines = []

for s in table_read:
    lines.append(s)
    
ordered_table = list(map(map_ids_to_row_list, names))
    
with open(new_name,'w') as fs:
    for row in ordered_table:
        fs.write(str(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
l = [4324,3245,3114,1211]
df.A = df.A.astype("category")
df.A = df.A.cat.set_categories(l)
df.sort_values(["A"])
```

Output:

```
      A           B
4   4324    sssvdff
5   4324    weewr
6   4324    bla
7   4324    orange
1   3245    ssssd
2   3114    dsf
3   3114    apple
0   1211    ds
8   1211    something
9   1211    blue
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482668/sorting-by-a-custom-list-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to fall back to native python sorting -

```py
order_list = [4324, 3245, 3114, 1211]
pd.DataFrame.from_records(sorted(df.to_records(index=False), key=lambda x: order_list.index(x[0])), columns=df.columns)
```

**Output**

```
      A          B
0  4324    sssvdff
1  4324      weewr
2  4324        bla
3  4324     orange
4  3245      ssssd
5  3114        dsf
6  3114      apple
7  1211         ds
8  1211  something
9  1211       blue
```